# Shopify: how to clone a store to set up dev environment

Tags: shopify

Is there really NO way to duplicate an entire Shopify store? By this, I mean theme files, navigation, pages, posts, images, apps etc? I'm actually not overly concerned with the "store". part of it as my tasks are all enhancements to the pages and blog posts.... I have tried several apps (alone and in combination... Matrixify and Exlm...), but none seem to be able to do it all... definitely not navigation or apps. most images seem to be missing but not all - this is kind of confusing. Certain CSS seems to be left intact while other styles are missing. In addition to not being able to show the client an accurate depiction of the enhancements, I'm terrified to use these tools to copy changes back for fear that something is going to be overwritten.

Has anyone nailed down a good process for establishing a good dev and/or stage environment for a live Shopify store?

Comment: There is no way to do the same using any APP or custom coding. you need to setup manually step by step and use it

Comment: @Onkar thanks for confirming. That is mind-blowing to me. Note to self: encourage clients to keep all non-store content out of Shopify.